# Reusing figure in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I am looking to reuse a matplotlib figure multiple times in an animation. The basic workflow is:

1. Run some code
2. Visualize the results

and repeat steps 1, 2 multiple times. The reason I wish to use the same `figure` instance is so that I donot have new windows popping up.

Here is sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def init_animate(fig):
  #plt.ion()
  #fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  im_obj = ax.imshow(np.zeros((200,200,3)).astype(np.uint8))
  #return fig, im_obj
  return im_obj

def animate(i, im_obj):
  im = np.zeros((200,200,3)).astype(np.uint8)
  if np.mod(i,45) < 15:
    im[:,:,0] = 255
  elif np.mod(i,45) < 30:
    im[:,:,1] = 255
  else:
    im[:,:,2] = 255
  im_obj.set_data(im)
  return im_obj,

def run_animate():
  fig = plt.figure()
  fig.set_animated(True)
  for i in range(5):
    im_obj = init_animate(fig)
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=45,
interval=15, blit=False, fargs=[im_obj], repeat=False)
    plt.ion()
    plt.show(block=False)
    matplotlib.interactive(False)
    fig.clf(keep_observers=True)
```

When I run `run_animate`, I see the animation only once, but not all five times. If I create a new `figure` in the `for` loop, everything works as expected. Any pointers on what I might be missing?

Comment: please provide a runnable code